# What Language For Image Recognition In Conjunction With Robotics

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition, robotics

I have some basic general coding knowledge but have never delved into one language very much. I am interested in creating a program that utilizes image recognition in a live video feed to control a robot. I want to be able to identify specific objects in the image. I'm thinking of using an Arduino or Raspberry Pi to control the robot and possibly a USB webcam or serial camera for capturing the image.

I'm wondering what language would be best suited for the image processing in real-time, working in conjunction with my robot, being able to feed the program data (images) for it to learn and other factors I may not have considered that might be necessary for this application.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because asking for recommendations of tools, software or off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow, however my suggestion would be that an Arduino is too underpowered and you should use a Raspberry Pi and OpenCV with Python to get started.

Answer (score 0):

C++ and python are the best I can think of

OpenCV is standard.  But doubt it can recognize face fast enough on Raspberry PI. Usually, we use Keras for running more state of the art code on the striped notebook motherboard with GPU. sth like the image below. You can get it at PC repair shop. Just say you need a replacement motherboard. quite ez to get.

Arduino is for simple control. e.g two servo. But if you need to program the robot to do sth advanced e.g path planning, homolomic control, ROS is more ideal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I'll do some more research.

Comment: You dont need research, you need to do projects. Once you have a clear goal and some1 willing to pay you, you will be motivated to get things done :)